Python - need more than one value / only value - subprocess powershell
I need some help please.
I only need the values ​​in two Python variables from a simple Powershell query in Python with two results.
Powershell Result
Variable 1: myPC
Variable 2: 28.05.2024
Can anyone help?
...
data = subprocess.run('get-adcomputer -identity myPC -properties * | select name, created', text=True, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, executable=powershell_path)
data = data.stdout.strip()

result1 = ????
result2 = ????

Thanks
Output as text:

name         created            
----         -------            
myPC     28.05.2024 07:49:56

i tried everything :)

Please add output of your command as text.

Try adding ... | select name,created | ConvertTo-Json. This should return json result, then you may load/convert it into python objects

Thank you very much! That was my food for thought

You can use one of the PowerShell converters to put it into an interpretable format such as CSV or JSON.  Then use Python to read in from that format.
import json 

cmd = 'get-adcomputer -identity myPC -properties * | select name,created | ConvertTo-Json'
data = subprocess.run(cmd, text=True, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, executable=powershell_path)
data = json.loads(data.stdout)


Also thank you. I implemented it exactly the same way.

You already have data containing the string of all the output, so the answer is a combination of string manipulation to get what you want. If you are confident in the output of the powershell command to always give the same format it could be as easy as searching for the line containing ---- then splitting all subsequent lines based on whitespace:
data = """\
name         created            
----         -------            
myPC     28.05.2024 07:49:56"""

lines = data.split("\n")
lineiter = iter(lines)
for line in lineiter:  # iterate lines until we find the "----"
    if  "----" in line:
        break
for line in lineiter:  # then go over the rest of the lines (presumably just one?)
    line_items = line.split()  # split with no args defaults to splitting on any whitespace.
    result1 = line_items[0]
    result2 = line_items[1]

